# Выполняется код в блоке if который выполнятся не должен

Tags: php, css

```
if ( ! uri_empty('location') ) { die;

        $db->query("UPDATE users SET gold = 10 WHERE id = $ID");

        // Чистка базы с боем
        $db->query("DELETE users_battle WHERE id_user = $ID");

        // Чистка лога
        $db->query("DELETE users_log WHERE id_user = ".ID." ");
    }
```

uri_empty('location) всегда возвращает правдивое значение, но уж точно не false. В коде вы можете наблюдать, что я поставил die в самом начале конструкции и представьте себе запросы в базу все одно идут. Я уже с ума схожу, помогите!

Только что выяснил, что это происходит из-за подключаемого css-стиля.
Что в css файле может такого что влияло бы на сам url или на скрипт???

```
html, body {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    max-width : 320px;
    margin : auto;
    font-family: "Arial";
    background: url(../graphic/elements/4.png) repeat-y #000;

    text-shadow: 0 0px 0 #;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px #;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

a {text-decoration: underline;color: #015292;}
label {padding-left: 7%;padding-bottom: 5px;display: inline-block;padding-top: 10px;}
.labelike {padding-left: 7%;padding-bottom: 5px;display: inline-block;padding-top: 10px;}
img {border:0 none;vertical-align:middle;}
b {font-weight:bold; color: #005892;}
h4 {margin: 15px 0 5px;}


.container{
    position: relative;
    color: #BEBEBE;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px black;
    background-color: #08141b;
}
.inner-content {
background:url('../graphic/elements/3.png') repeat-x #08141b;
padding: 15px;
border: 0px;
color: #fff;
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #ddd5a8;
}

 /* Вход  */
.main-head{
background: url('../graphic/elements/2.png') repeat-x #0f191d;
text-align: center;
border: 3px;
color: #b8ad71;
}

input[type~="text"], 
input[type~="select"], 
input[type~="password"], 
input[type~="number"]{
        border-bottom: 1px solid #473c2a;
        border-top: 1px solid #473c2a;
        border-left: 1px solid #473c2a;
        border-right: 1px solid #473c2a;
        color: #fff;
        margin: 2px;
        background: #222722;
        width:257px;
        height: 50px;
        outline:none;
        padding-left: 17px;

}
input[type~="password"] {
        margin-top: -15px;
}
input[type="submit"] {
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000000;
border: 0px solid #000;
        color: #000;
        background: url(../graphic/elements/5.png);
        width:141px;
        height: 35px;
        outline:none;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-size: 16px;
        text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #36466e;
}

input[type="submit"]:hover {
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #070f1d;
border: 0px solid #000;
        color: #000;
        background: url(../graphic/elements/5.png);
        width:141px;
        height: 35px;
        outline:none;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-size: 16px;
        text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #36466e;
}


 /* Нижний бар */
.index   {
        color: #344680;
    padding: 7px;
        text-align: center;
        }

 /* Ссылки меню */      
.links a {
background : #1b3039;
color : #FFFAF0;
text-decoration : none;
padding : 7px;
font-weight : bold;
display : block;
border-top : 1px solid #435964;
border-bottom : 1px solid #0f1a20;
border-left : 1px solid #0f1a20;
border-right : 1px solid #0f1a20;
}
.links a:hover {
background : #1b3039;
}

.nav{
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 75px; /*54*/
}
.nav a{
    display: table-cell;
    text-decoration : none;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    border-top: 1px solid #4E4E4E;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #08141b;
}
.nav a.home,
.nav a.char,
.nav a.clan{
    background-position: 50% 5px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.nav a.home{background-image: url("../graphic/icons/glav.png")}
.nav a.char{background-image: url("../graphic/icons/pers.png")}
.nav a.clan{background-image: url("../graphic/icons/sum.png")}


.nev{
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 75px; /*54*/
}
.nev a{
    display: table-cell;
    text-decoration : none;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    border-top: 1px solid #4E4E4E;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #1b3039;
}
.nev a.ob,
.nev a.ok{
    background-position: 50% 5px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.nev a.ob{background-image: url("../graphic/icons/ob.png")}
.nev a.ok{background-image: url("../graphic/icons/ok.png")}



.header
{
    background-color: #687946;
}
.pip
{
    position: relative;
    height: 40px;
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62067/discussion-on-question-by-erepaha-----if--).

Answer (score 0):

Возможно дело в условии и стоит использовать isset?

```
if ( isset(uri_empty('location'))
```

Comment: Знак вопроса смущает. Это вопрос или утверждение?

Comment: Вроде isset так не работает?